# Why VLC doesn't record audio when streaming YouTube video

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, youtube

I am able to record YouTube video by going into `Media --> Open Network Stream` which saves it in MKV format. Problem is when I play the recorded file in VLC, it doesn't have any audio. Is this a known problem in VLC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube has separate audio and video streams, broken into segments, for most files. There are some browser extensions that enable the download and combination of the segments and streams, such as Firefox addon [Flash Video Downloader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-video-downloader/) and application [Free Download Manager](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) for Windows OS.

Note that many of these tools require an additional application to reconnect the pieces of the stream afterwards, using ffmpeg in the background.